# cURL PHP post not going through but ReturnTransfer is working

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I have a newsletter plugin which requires I send form email data to myurl.com/?na=s

The name of the email field needs to be 'ne'

I'm trying to use cURL to submit subscriber data to the newsletter plugin. This is the code I'm using now:

```
$address = $_POST['emailer'];

$curlvars = [
    'na' => 's',
    'ne' => $address
];

$ch = curl_init('http://www.myurl.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

This code is all within a php file called send.php which I send the data to through ajax. The send.php file emails the subscriber an email and also submits the subscriber's email to the newsletter plugin.

I added $result to that email so I can see the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER output.

When I enter my own email (for testing) into the form field and click submit, I get the email and at the bottom I get a "subscribe" button (the output of the RETURNTRANSFER).

The subscribe button's data in Inspect Element is:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.myURL.com/" id="m_-3594728259508176106form" target="_blank" onsubmit="try {return window.confirm(&quot;You are submitting information to an external page.\nAre you sure?&quot;);} catch (e) {return false;}">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="/10442-2/"><input type="hidden" name="na" value="s"><input type="hidden" name="ne" value="myemail@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="ts" value="1475753672">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

If I click it, it will submit the email successfully to my newsletter plugin.

Basically, cURL ReturnTransfer output is showing everything correctly but it's not actually POSTing the data to my site when I submit from the site. Only when I hit the generated submit button in the email I receive.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem in your curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS) function..

you need to change the postfield like this ..

```
 @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curlvars ));
 @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

try this code ..
in server side dont forgot to json_decode() the coming data

Comment: he can use the `http_build_query()` also.

Comment: Where should I be decoding the json data? I'm not very familiar with json. For http_build_query, I tried to change postfields to: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($curlvars)); and it didn't work. Same results

Comment: @Ram in your server side that is the server that handling curl request .from your example http://www.myurl.com/

Comment: What is the purpose of json'ing the data? The plugin to where I am sending the data was not coded by me and only needs 1 piece of data (subscriber's email). Is just submitting data to a URL with POST using cURL not enough? Is there another way that does not require json as I'm not sure what to do server side.